# How do I send an email with a PDF attachment not from the user's email in Swift?

Tags: swift, email, pdf

I have app where the user can enter some information, after which it generates into a PDF. I would like the user then be able to send that PDF to people via email, but not from their own email. EX: Say my app's name was Chair and I have a support@chair.com email address. I would want the PDF to be sent to the recipients from that support@chair.com email.

I've looked at the Gmail SDK but it looks like that it only lets you do Gmail sign-in. I also looked at MailCore, but it hasn't been updated for a long time and I don't think it supports Swift.

Comment: I guess your data should be sent to your backend, where the PDF will be generated and server should send the email, not your mobile app client.

Comment: are you using  MFMailComposeViewController ?

Comment: I don't want the user to send the email through MFMailComposer. Think of it like when you sign up for a service and it sends you a welcome email.

Comment: it is better to send a email by backend team instead of app.

Comment: So what backend team should I use? My database is on Firebase but I don't think they do emailing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this tutorial to work for those who are reading this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkpLqNN8xtU